# Password hash using django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

I figured out that `django-auth` hashes passwords per default with random salt in the background: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/

However, I am not quite sure yet, what's the difference between `django-auth` and `django-rest-auth`.

And I could not find information whether `django-rest-auth` will also hash and salt passwords automatically.

Could someone explain what exactly the differences are between `django-auth` and `django-rest-auth`, when to choose which and why there are two libraries for the same problem?

It is quite confusing for me as a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-rest-auth`'s documentation [explains the purpose of the project](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) pretty well:

> Since the introduction of django-rest-framework, Django apps have been able to serve up app-level REST API endpoints. As a result, we saw a lot of instances where developers implemented their own REST registration API endpoints here and there, snippets, and so on. We aim to solve this demand by providing django-rest-auth, a set of REST API endpoints to handle User Registration and Authentication tasks. By having these API endpoints, your client apps such as AngularJS, iOS, Android, and others can communicate to your Django backend site independently via REST APIs for User Management. Of course, we’ll add more API endpoints as we see the demand.

The project exists to provide a set of common API endpoints for authentication. It doesn't handle authentication tasks itself, so it doesn't have to worry about things like password hashing.

For example, its [`PasswordChangeSerializer` uses](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/c009bb997509fed2d7a544d54b25322efbee57d9/rest_auth/serializers.py#L259-L272) the [`SetPasswordForm` from `django.contrib.auth`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/c009bb997509fed2d7a544d54b25322efbee57d9/rest_auth/serializers.py#L3). It gets to use all the good stuff that Django's built-in auth framework provides.

Comment: Thank you very much, this clarifies many things for me!
So I can basically say that the `django-rest-framework` or better, `django-rest-auth` uses `django-auth` behind the scenes without me having to worry about it?

Comment: @ElectRocnic, by default, yes. You can override a bunch of stuff if you really want to but out of the box it exposes Django's built-in auth over API endpoints.